# hive server pushing parquet timestamp values by one hour in BST timezone

Tags: hive, parquet, hdp

'HDP--3.1.4,The table containing the parquet timestamp which has hourly data ,hive server  is pushing the hour data into into next date example is shown below , please check before and after 29 th Mar 2020 , where Mar 29 is the BST time settings with day light saving'

```
| 2020-03-22  | 2020-03-22 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-22 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-23  | 2020-03-23 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-23 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-24  | 2020-03-24 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-24 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-25  | 2020-03-25 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-25 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-26  | 2020-03-26 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-26 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-27  | 2020-03-27 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-27 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-28  | 2020-03-28 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-28 23:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-29  | 2020-03-29 00:00:59.0  | 2020-03-30 00:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-30  | 2020-03-30 01:00:59.0  | 2020-03-31 00:59:59.0  |
| 2020-03-31  | 2020-03-31 01:00:59.0  | 2020-04-01 00:59:59.0  |
| 2020-04-01  | 2020-04-01 01:00:59.0  | 2020-04-02 00:59:59.0  |
| 2020-04-02  | 2020-04-02 01:00:59.0  | 2020-04-03 00:59:59.0  |
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing to parquet table in hive make sure the timestamp values are in UTC and set time zone in hive to match the local timezone .

```
set time zone LOCAL;
 or 
set time zone '+1:00'
```